# In camel can I use marshalling in my bean processor?

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I have a camel route defined in Spring-XML and I'm using marshall and unmarshall to convert between JSON and my domain object. All works great, here's my question though:

I'm calling a method on bean as part of my route which saves the JSON representation of my domain object to a repository. This method needs access to certain properties on my domain object in order to save it in the right place, and also needs the JSON representation to save; so either I:

1) Set the a header to the value of my domain object and then marshall the object into my body (my bean now has access to both representations)

2) Set the domain object as the body and have my bean marshall it back to JSON

option 1 is what I'm doing but seems wasteful since I'm storing both representations of the object, can I do option 2 and reuse the marshalling logic in my bean?

Answer (score 0):

Why not? If you have the ObjectMapper bean defined in Spring, you can get it and use inside your method to marshall the java object with it.

Edit: adding below -

```
    ApplicationContext ac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
    CamelContext ctx = (CamelContext) ac.getBean("camel");
    ModelCamelContext Mctx = (ModelCamelContext) ctx;
    JsonDataFormat fmt = (JsonDataFormat) Mctx.getDataFormats().get("jack");
```

This should fetch you the dataformat...

Comment: That's my question - how do I do this? I'm defining the marshaling within a <dataformats> element within my camel context, not as a regular spring bean.

Comment: Posting a snippet of your route would be helpful here. But I've added a way to fetch dataformat information from within the camel context. Obviously is a work around and maybe, nicer solutions exist.